# MEANjs - Issues working with Angular/Express Users Resource API

Tags: angularjs, express, meanjs

I'm looking for some help understanding some of the API parts used in MEANjs, in particular the Users resource.  Basically I've been working on a MEAN app for a bit now, working off their basic version of the site and using the yeoman meanjs generator, and am trying to extend what they have.  What I'm working to implement is an Administrator being able to change a user's roles attribute, so they can be changed from a "user" to an "admin."

I'll try to post all the code that I think is relevant and my understanding of what it does, and hopefully a solution can be found.

In the users.client.controller, this function is called on a button press, $scope.user is the user we are trying to make an admin:

```
$scope.test = function(){
        $scope.user.roles[0]= 'admin';
        var currUser = $scope.user;
        Users.updateUserRoles(currUser);
};
```

So it makes them an admin, copies it over to another variable, and calls the Users Resource's function, updateUserRoles, which is here:

```
exports.updateUserRoles = function(req, res) { 
    var currUser = req.body;
    User.findById(currUser._id, function(err, user) {
        user.roles = currUser.roles;
        user.save();
    });
};
```

So that function finds in the User Resource the user that has the same _id as the passed user, and sets that user's roles as the passed users, and then saves that user.  This is where I'm the most shaky, the save call on the user should call a POST method in the resource, I believe, which is here:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('users/:userId', {userId: '@_id'}, {
            updateUserRoles: {
                method: 'POST',
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
            }       
        });
    }
]);
```

Also here are the users.server.routes that include all the options, some that aren't even implemented yet:

```
app.route('/users/:userId').get(users.read)
                               .put(users.requiresLogin, users.update)
                               .delete(users.requiresLogin);
                               .post(users.updateUserRoles);
```

So after all that, the main problem I'm having, is that the user's roles is indeed changed to "admin," but when everything is said and done, the user's password has been changed.  I'm running a database on MongoLab, and after their role is changed you can very easily see the password hash has been altered, and trying to log into an account that has had its roles changed is unsuccessful.  I had hoped to put in breakpoints in some more of the functions, but in chrome you can only look at js files in certain directories, so I'm not 100% sure how to tell exactly what is happening after the function is called.

Anyone have any ideas?  I can supply any more code that might be needed.

Comment: Have you tried to use console.log() with Chrome on Dev Mode (F12)?
What is the new password? Is it the default one or an undefined value? Can you check if a new user was created?

Comment: I've tried some console.log() statements, but for some reason haven't had success in getting any ones server side to actually print.  And I don't know the new password, on MongoLab I see the password hash changing, but have no idea what its changed to, its random every time.  And no, no new users have been created.